# Как правильно использовать события в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как правильно использовать события на добавления в БД новых данных в yii2. Есть две связанные таблицы, и нужно отследить событие когда добавиться запись в одну, чтобы мы добавили запись и в вторую.

Пытаюсь так но что-то не работает событие

И ошибки:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 

public function addB()
    { 



        $model2 = new NameDB();

        $tim = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

        if($this->comment !== null){
        $model2->comment = $this->comment;
        }

        if($this->userurl_password !== null){
        $model2->userurl_password = $this->userurl_password;
        }


       Event::on($model2->save(), ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT, function ($event) {
             //тут вызываем метод добавления записи в другую таблицу
            });



    }
```

Comment: может тригеры лучше использовать в mysql https://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/

Comment: Не советуют. Раньше я их использовал.

Comment: Текст ошибки вам говорит что не может обновить или вставить строку, так как нарушен первичный ключ или его вообще  нет. По идеи вы должны просто добавить первичный ключ для таблички(сущности). К примеру если добавлять id(как auto increment), то он автоматом станет первичным.

Answer (score 2):

По тексту ошибки видно, что нарушенны ограничения целостности данных по внешним ключам (*foreign keys*).

Скорее всего, внешний ключ, который Вы пытаетесь вставить во вторую таблицу, отсутствует в качестве первичного ключа в первой таблице.

Для того, чтобы лучше разобраться, что у Вас там происходит было бы неплохо привести запрос `CREATE TABLE` ваших таблиц и код вот этого места: `//тут вызываем метод добавления записи в другую таблицу`.

Если Вы пытаетесь, скажем, сначала, сразу же после того, как произошло событие, вставить записи в таблицу, а потом откуда-то получить `id` вставленной записи из первой таблицы, той, что спровоциравала событие, и затем обновить этим ключом запись (к примеру, `$model->setSomeForeignKey($model2->id); $model->update();`), то так сделать не получится, потому что вставка строки в первую таблицу, с внешним ключом, которого нету во второй таблице, вызывает ошибку, которая у Вас и вылетает.

Копайте в эту сторону, просмотрите в yii`шном дебаггере список запросов, их последовательность, проверьте, чтобы на момент вставки записи во вторую таблицу, в первой таблице присутствовала запись с первичным ключом, на которую ссылался бы внешний ключ второй таблицы.